# High Availability Solution for VM on local Storage

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

Hi I have the following setup for using vSphere with HA:

[image]

My problem with this is the finding some kind of reasonable HA for the database server. The IOP requirements of the database server are very high, as such the database files are spread across three local SSD raid 10 arrays.  The storage network is 10gbE and while it wouldn't meet the performance requirements long term I would like to have a way to have an automatic fail over to shared storage in the event that the Host fails.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could do this ?  Perhaps pick up to the last image backup on shared storage ?

Thanks

*on vmware essentials plus.

Comment: If you have Veeam, you could use Veeam Replication to replicate that VM to ESXi standby failover host.

Comment: I'm fairly certain, unfortunately, that VMware HA doesn't have that capability (that I'm aware of), but you might look into a virtual storage appliance that can create shared storage from the local storage on both hosts and allow for failover between hosts for VM's running on that local storage. VMware, HP and StarWind are just a few that have an HA VSA solution.

Comment: Which DB and engine? MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MSSQL?

Comment: @GioMac MSSQL, If I couldn't come up with something I was contemplating log shipping to a secondary and having a listening service.  Problem is there are some other services running on here (third partty ISV) so it would be sketchy at best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [vSphere Storage Appliance](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-storage-appliance/) can "share" local storage between different vmware hosts, but I don't think its included in essentials plus.  There is [vSphere Replication](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/features-replication), which is a vmware appliance that could replicate the database VM and its local storage to another host's local storage.  Its also included in essentials plus.  However, its not going to be automated like vSphere HA (at least I don't think so) and you're not going to get better than a 15min RPO.  If that's acceptable, its probably the best choice.

The better solution would be to re-examine the database's IO requirements and look into a SAN that can support its and the rest of your cluster's needs.  Most SAN manufacturers offer SSD options. Or, if that's not a possiblity, then maybe moving the DB to dedicated hardware and leveraging the application's HA offerings (Oracle RAC/dataguard, mysql master-master, etc) to meet your needs.

Comment: vSphere replication and the storage appliance are available for Essentials Plus.

Comment: @ewwhite Are you sure ? http://store.vmware.com/store/vmware/Content/pbPage.vSphereComparePageThat would actually be what I need dont have enterprise licensing otpion.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna Yes, the replication and storage appliance are included.

Comment: The vSphere Storage Appliance won't support the I/O requirements the OP is asking for. It's probably time to wait for [**VMware's VSAN**](http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/tag/vsan)

Answer (score 2):

StarWind has a native Hyper-V implementation. They do sell this since 2011. VMware has the same thing called vSAN being currently in beta. So StarWind had visioned the future long before whole IT industry had moved to the right direction :) Key point here - run inside HYPERVISOR and not inside a guest VM. Cheers! Ichiro

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a third-party synchronous or asynchronous data replication package like [SIOS SteelEye](http://us.sios.com/windows-replication-availability-software-smb/). This is cluster-management software that will allow you to have one or more mirrors of the same server, managing service failover, IP addresses and of course, data.

But really, you're avoiding one of the better features of VMware: High availability. Is there any way to improve the capabilities of your NAS? Perhaps you can use host-level caching for ESXi.

Please outline the IOPS requirements of your database server.

Comment: Currently 3 Raid 10 arrays with 8 Drives per array and 1gb Battery backed Perc Controllers.  @~60-100 IOps per array.  To get this from shared storage "I think" I'd need a very expensive Fiber Channel SAN.  Hence the hack around

Comment: Only 60-100 IOps per array seems really low.  a Single 15k SAS drive can give 150-200 IOPS, while SSDs are typically 1000+.

Comment: @Bob I was saying 60,000 -100,000.  Truth is your really saturating the controller before anything else tho.